# How can I avoid requesting redox-saga action several times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

If an error occurs when executing the getPost function, I want to run REFRESH_REQUEST through catch (err), and when REFRESH_SUCCESS is complete, I want to run GETPOST_REQUEST again.

However, with my code, GETPOST_REQUEST and REFRESH_REQUEST run multiple times and GETPOST_GETPOST_SUCCESS succeeds first.

However, I want the both REQUEST to be executed only once, and the REFRESH_SUCCESS succeeds first and then the second I want GETPOST_SUCCESS to succeed.

this is my code how can i fix my code?

```
    function getPostAPI(data) {
      return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/getpost', data);
    }

    function* getPost(action) {
      try {
        const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
        yield put({
          type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_REQUEST,
        });
        yield put({
          type: GETPOST_REQUEST,
          data: action.data,
        });
      }
    }

    function refreshAPI() {
      return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/refresh');
    }

    function* refresh() {
      try {
        const result = yield call(refreshAPI);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('accesstoken', `${result.data.accessToken}`, () => {});
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_SUCCESS,
          data: result.data,
        });
      } catch (err) {
        yield put({
          type: REFRESH_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

maintain `reducer` with `status` of api calling like below

initially, store contains status equal to initial

so when one `action` called, make status to loading and dont call action if its already loading state...

Note: I explained this code in `redux-thunk` way, but try to understand the logic, it will be same wherever.

I hope you understand

```
type status = 'initial' | 'loading' | 'success' | 'error';

const initialState = {
  status: 'initial'
}
```

in `getPost` error function, you can check for the status of api...

```
const getPost = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    GETPOST_REQUEST;
    try {
      GETPOST_SUCCESS;
    } catch(error) {
      GETPOST_ERROR;
      
      if (state.status !== 'loading') {
        dispatch(refresh())
      }
    }
  }
}

const refresh = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState();
    REFRESH_REQUEST;
    try {
      REFRESH_SUCCESS;
      dispatch(getPost())
    } catch(error) {
      REFRESH_ERROR;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: umm i don;t understand... can you show me according to my code?

Comment: So what you mean is to refresh when it's an error and not loading?